# Using PhpSpreadsheet to add an image using a URL or base64

Tags: php, image, url, base64, phpspreadsheet

I have been trying out PhpSpreadsheet, and so far it's working well. However, I'm stuck on adding an image to the spreadsheet. In my database, I have both external image URLs (ex: http://somewhere.com/imagename.png) and base64 image data. Is it possible to display these as images in the spreadsheet?

Comment: Did you check this: https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/develop/topics/recipes/#add-a-drawing-to-a-worksheet

Comment: Yes, definitely. However, the path appears to be a local path:
$drawing->setPath('./images/officelogo.jpg');
I would like to do this with external URLs and base64 image data.

Comment: Have you tried that code linking an external image? If it doesn't work, try getting the image in base64 and storing it somewhere in a tmp folder.

Comment: I tried linking to an external image, but I got an "image not found" error. I ended up saving the image in a temp folder and referencing it locally. Thanks!